# How to solve the dependencies of building ignite 2.8 source code?

Tags: maven, ignite

I am trying to build ignite 2.8 in windows 10, my java version is 1.8, and maven 3.8.5.
I build source code with the command below:

```
mvn clean install -P all-java,all-scala,licenses -DskipTests -D maven.javadoc.skip=true.
```

It failed and showed that:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ignite-jta: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ignite:ignite-jta:jar:2.8.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.ow2.jotm:jotm-core:jar:2.2.3 -> org.ow2.carol:carol:jar:3.0.8 -> org.jacorb:jacorb:jar:2.2.3-jonas-patch-20071018: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jacorb:jacorb:jar:2.2.3-jonas-patch-20071018: Could not transfer artifact org.jacorb:jacorb:pom:2.2.3-jonas-patch-20071018 from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, snapshots), ow2-snapshot (http://repository.ow2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots, default, snapshots), ow2 (http://maven.ow2.org/maven2, default, releases)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :ignite-jta
```

I have checked that the jar file of org.jacorb:jacorb:pom:2.2.3-jonas-patch-20071018 is no longer maintained in maven central and i cannot find its backup anywhere. I am not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: The first thing is that `from/to maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/): Blocked mirror for repositories: [apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots, default, snapshots), ow2-snapshot (http://repository.ow2.org/nexus/content/repositor`. this is one problem...

Comment: @khmarbaise is right but also... why Ignite 2.8.0? It's over two years old. You'll likely have better luck with 2.13, which is the current version.

Comment: The problem is not the version of ignite... This is related to the Maven version which is used and not configured the right way.... (See https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.8.1/release-notes.html)

Comment: Thanks to both of you two guys. I have to build ignite because I am testing and comparing the effectiveness of several static analysis tools, so I have to build lots of versions of ignite.  Let me have a look of the configuration of maven first.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have checked the issue mentioned in maven 3.8.1 and understand why they are blocked since then. However, the solution of changing configuration does not work for my case, as I cannot find another repository containing this dependency anywhere, so perhaps I have to degrade my maven version or use a wrapper.

Comment: Changing the maven version to 3.2.5 solves this problem, again, thanks, guys.

Comment: No it does not solve the problem. You are now vulnerabil. If changing the configuration does not work is the question: What exactly have you changed and what does it mean it does not work?